# Behavior of Ext under base change

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, spectral-sequences

Let $x$ be a nonzerodivisor on a local Noetherian ring $(R,m).$ Let $M,N$ be finitely generated $R/xR$-modules.

**How to show the existence of the following exact sequence**

$\cdots\longrightarrow Ext_{R/xR}^{n}(M,N)\longrightarrow Ext_{R}^{n}(M,N)\longrightarrow Ext_{R/xR}^{n-1}(M,N)\longrightarrow \cdots.$

Any reference will be useful.

Comment: I think the correct exact sequence is:
$$\cdots\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^n_{R/xR}(M,N)\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^n_{R}(M,N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^{n-1}_{R/xR}(M,N) \rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_{R/xR}(M,N)\rightarrow \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_{R}(M,N)\rightarrow \cdots$$
It is a particular case of the exact sequence (4) p. 44 of Bourbaki's *Algèbre commutative* X (unfortunately not yet translated into English, as far as I know).

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: @abx Could you please explain the answer.

Comment: Explain what? I gave you a reference, I thought this is what you were asking for.